# Java thread slowing Postgres DB update

Tags: java, multithreading, postgresql

I have a piece of legacy code which is basically like:

```
// instance variable
List<Future<Object>> futureList;

methodA() {
   List list = getListOfMessages();

   for (Object o : list) {
       methodB(o);
   }
}

void methodB(Object o) {
    // after multi-threading, this statement takes ~2 mins
    someDAO.update(o.value);

    // some other tasks
}
```

This works fine, except that I have about million records that are retrieved into list via `getListOfMessages()`. So I was asked to multithread it and I changed it to something like...

```
methodA() {
    List list = getListOfMessages();

    // created executorservice here

    for(Object o : list) {
       Future future = executorService.submit(methodB(o));     

       futureList.add(future);      
    }

    // call another method to see the status of each ask
    checkFutureStatus(futureList);
}

void checkFutureStatus(List<Future<Object>> list) {
    for(Future<Object> future : list) {
        try {
            future.get(1000, TimeUnit.Milliseconds);
        } catch (InterrupException | ExecutionExecption e) {
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

So basically, for each list item, I pass it to methodB but have it handled by separate threads. Once all threads have been submitted, I check the status of the threads but every thread throws a TimeoutException. On debugging, I see that the threads take too long for DB updates...like 1-2 min.

Just to be sure that the threads are not competing with each other, I had the getListOfMessages() return just one message. And even that is taking 1-2 min, If I just revert everything and go non threaded approach, the DB update takes 1ms. I can't really figure out why the multi-thread implementation is causing the db update to take so long.

I'm using Postgres 10 and the db update is via jdbctemplate.

Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Added method to explain how I'm checking the status of each thread.

Comment: What you do after methodA(). Do you call `Thread.yield();` or is current thread doing something else?

Comment: Inside the methodA() I keep a list of future tasks submitted via  executorService. Once the loop completes inside methodA(), I iterate over the list of tasks to check the status of each thread. I will edit the the question to include this @PirosaysReinstateMonica